# How can I speed up this mongodb query

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, query-optimization

I am trying to use MongoDB to save test run documents including their measured values and try to query them. I have about 36.5 million documents and they look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60619f84dc46fad865680ab8"),
    "uuid" : "47aad0e5-3e41-4951-8881-3ae70ae85bcd",
    "id_tb" : ObjectId("60619f84dc46fad865680225"),
    "code" : "",
    "ser" : "",
    "mat" : "",
    "state" : "",
    "ts_start" : ISODate("2018-01-01T18:46:56.000Z"),
    "ts_end" : ISODate("2018-01-01T18:47:20.000Z"),
    "ts_restart" : ISODate("2018-01-01T18:46:56.000Z"),
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "dtype" : "i",
            "v_int" : NumberLong(20030606),
            "key" : "x"
        }, 
        {
            "dtype" : "i",
            "v_int" : NumberLong(1208551142),
            "key" : "y"
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Each test run document has an array "values" that includes 730 subdocuments (one for each measured value).

I am using C# so my models looks like this:

```
    public class TestRun
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "uuid")]
        [BsonElement("uuid")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Uuid { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("id_tb")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public ObjectId IdTb{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
        [BsonElement("code")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "serial")]
        [BsonElement("ser")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mat")]
        [BsonElement("mat")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Mat { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "overall")]
        [BsonElement("state")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ts_start")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? TsStart { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ts_end")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? TsEnd { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ts_restart")]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime? TsRestart { get; set; }
        
        [BsonElement("values")]
        public List<TestRunValue> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestRunValue
    {
        [BsonElement("dtype")]
        public string Datatype { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("v_bool")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public bool? VBool { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("v_char")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public string? VChar { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("v_int")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public long? VInt { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("v_real")]
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public float? VReal { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
```

I created indices for the fields I am going to search for: `_id_`, `ser`, `mat`, `ts_start`, `ts_end`, `code` and `state`.
The total index size is about 1.8 GB, 257.2 MB average, with `ts_start` being biggest with 392.6 MB and `code` being smallest with 164.9 MB.

Test run documents are 52.3 KB on average.

To test querying this collection I use a .NET Core console application. The query looks like this:

```
var builder = Builders<TestRun>.Filter;
FilterDefinition<TestRun> filter = builder.Empty;
if (startTime != null)
    filter = builder.Gte(t => t.TsStart, startTime);

if (endTime != null)
    filter = filter & builder.Lte(t => t.TsEnd, endTime);

if (mats != null && mats.Count > 0)
    filter = filter & builder.In(t => t.Mat, mats);

if (sers != null && sers.Count > 0)
    filter = filter & builder.In(t => t.Serial, sers);
            
if (codes != null && codes.Count > 0)
    filter = filter & builder.In(t => t.Code, codes);
            
if (states != null && states.Count > 0)
    filter = filter & builder.In(t => t.State, states);
            
var query = context._testruns
    .Find(filter, new FindOptions() {Comment = "MyQuery"})
    .Limit(maxNumValues);

Console.WriteLine($"Running query: \n {query.ToString()}");

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            
List<TestRun> trs = query.ToList();

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Query took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
```

Now I run this query using

- `2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` as `startTime`
- `2018-01-01T23:59:59.000Z` as `endTime`
- `5000` as `maxNumValues`

which results in the following query:

```
find({
   "ts_start" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z") },
   "ts_end" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:59:59Z") }
}).limit(5000)._addSpecial("$comment", "MyQuery")
```

This takes a long time to finish. Even after 30 minutes it did not finish.
Even if I use a smaller period of time (`2018-01-01T23:00:00Z` - `2018-01-01T23:59:59Z`) and a smaller limit (200) it takes a long time.

I tested with more limits:

- limit 10 takes 340 ms
- limit 50 takes 543 ms
- limit 75 takes 615 ms
- limit 80 takes 749 ms
- limit 81 took several minutes

When running explain with limit 81 (in Robo 3T) it seems that it executed in 40286 ms:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "db.runs",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "ts_end" : {
                        "$lte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:59:59.000Z")
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "ts_start" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 81,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "ts_start" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "ts_end" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "ts_end",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "ts_end" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "ts_end" : [ 
                            "(true, new Date(1514851199000)]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ 
            {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 81,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "ts_end" : {
                            "$lte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:59:59.000Z")
                        }
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "ts_start" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "ts_start",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "ts_start" : []
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "ts_start" : [ 
                                "[new Date(1514847600000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 80,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 40286,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 248196,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 248196,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "nReturned" : 80,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 11268,
            "works" : 248198,
            "advanced" : 80,
            "needTime" : 248116,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 4036,
            "restoreState" : 4036,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "limitAmount" : 81,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "ts_start" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 80,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 11263,
                "works" : 248198,
                "advanced" : 80,
                "needTime" : 248116,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 4036,
                "restoreState" : 4036,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "docsExamined" : 248196,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 248196,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 228,
                    "works" : 248197,
                    "advanced" : 248196,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 4036,
                    "restoreState" : 4036,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "ts_end" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "ts_end",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "ts_end" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "ts_end" : [ 
                            "(true, new Date(1514851199000)]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 248196,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.2.13",
        "gitVersion" : "82dd40f60c55dae12426c08fd7150d79a0e28e23"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1620127924, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1620127924, 1)
}
```

I tried running `explain()` using mongo shell instead of Robo 3T to see if it makes a difference.
It takes forever and what I could see in resource monitor is, that while running, mongod and System were reading data from disk.

My console application and MongoDB (version 4.2) both run on Windows Server 2012 with 32GB RAM.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve performance or how I could find what is causing this?

**Edit:**
Here is the `explain("executionStats")` output of a query that took really long:

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "db.runs",
    "command" : {
        "find" : "runs",
        "filter" : {
            "ts_start" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:00:00.000Z")
            },
            "ts_end" : {
                "$lte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:59:59.000Z")
            }
        },
        "limit" : 81,
        "comment" : "MyQuery",
        "$db" : "db",
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : UUID("562115f5-059d-441a-96ad-e9da6702c962")
        }
    },
    "keysExamined" : 248196,
    "docsExamined" : 248196,
    "fromMultiPlanner" : true,
    "replanned" : true,
    "replanReason" : "cached plan was less efficient than expected: expected trial execution to take 81 works but it took at least 810 works",
    "cursorExhausted" : true,
    "numYield" : 73223,
    "nreturned" : 80,
    "queryHash" : "8927FA09",
    "planCacheKey" : "EFB63FF1",
    "locks" : {
        "ParallelBatchWriterMode" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(73225)
            }
        },
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(73225)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(73224)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(73224)
            }
        },
        "Mutex" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "flowControl" : {},
    "storage" : {
        "data" : {
            "bytesRead" : NumberLong(37794055022),
            "timeReadingMicros" : NumberLong(1394728348)
        }
    },
    "responseLength" : 4283172,
    "protocol" : "op_msg",
    "millis" : 1418283,
    "planSummary" : "IXSCAN { ts_end: 1 }",
    "execStats" : {
        "stage" : "LIMIT",
        "nReturned" : 80,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 500618,
        "works" : 248197,
        "advanced" : 80,
        "needTime" : 248116,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 73217,
        "restoreState" : 73217,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "limitAmount" : 81,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "ts_start" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2018-01-01T23:00:00.000Z")
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 80,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 500574,
            "works" : 248197,
            "advanced" : 80,
            "needTime" : 248116,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 73217,
            "restoreState" : 73217,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "docsExamined" : 248196,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 248196,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 707,
                "works" : 248197,
                "advanced" : 248196,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 73217,
                "restoreState" : 73217,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "ts_end" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "ts_end",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "ts_end" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "ts_end" : [ 
                        "(true, new Date(1514851199000)]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 248196,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2021-05-04T19:13:02.342Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Comment: The query might benefit from a compound index on the two date fields.

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you. I created an index `{ "ts_start": 1, "ts_end": 1}` but unfortunately all queries that use a limit > 80 still take really long. Explain shows that it rejects the query plan that uses this index. I tried using hint to make it use the new index but the queries still take a long time.

Comment: Use IAsyncCursor to retrieve data in C#, in FindOptions, use Projection to materialize only the properties you are interested in and set a BatchSize.